# How to find local maxima of the first column of dataset in C++

Tags: c++

Here is the code with which I store the .txt file:

```
ifstream f("file.txt");
string str1;

if (f.is_open())
{
getline(f,str1);
while(f)
{
    cout << str1 << endl;
    getline(f, str1);
}
f.close();
}
}
```

The problem is, that the str1[i] access the i-th symbol of the whole dataset. I'd like to find all local maxima of the second column of the dataset. Here is the example of the dataset:

```
15497.97740 -0.174807
15497.99247 0.410084
15498.00754 0.680590
15498.02260 -0.887408
15498.03767 -1.383546
15498.05273 -0.741141
```

Comment: The title to your question says you want to find the local maxima in the first column the body says second column.  Assuming these are the points you probably want to load them into a vector of points and then work on them.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways that you can do this is to load the second column into a vector and then find maximum element in that vector. You can read your file either by lines or by individual numbers using `std::fstream`s `operator>>(double)`. The second approach seems simpler in this case.

Notice that you don't need to manually close the file since the file is closed automatically in `std::fstream`s destructor.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::fstream ifs("data.txt");
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<double> secondColumn;

    // read the file skipping the first column
    double d1;
    double d2;
    while (ifs >> d1 && ifs >> d2)
    {
        secondColumn.push_back(d2);
    }

    // use the algorithm library to find the max element
    // std::max_element returns end iterator if the vector is empty
    // so an additional check is needed 
    auto maximumIt = std::max_element(secondColumn.begin(), secondColumn.end());
    if (maximumIt != secondColumn.end())
    {
        double maximum = *maximumIt;
        std::cout << maximum << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: small note: yes, the fstream is closed in the destructor. In this case that means the file will remain opened until the end of main... which is way after you're finished with it. I would usually put the fsteam object in a local (sub)scope. Or even put the whole initialization of `secondColumn` in an immediately invoked closure object (lambda)... so it can even be made const.

Comment: Yes I agree. I personally would use a function for loading the data or, as you mentioned, IILambda, however I wanted to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say, but your question is not fully clear to me. Sorry for that.

Anyway, I will try to help. I will find ALL local maxima.

We will split down the big problems into small problems, with classes and methods. That is then easier to solve.

Let's start with the basic element. A point on a curve. We will create a mini class, containing an “x” and “y”, assuming that this is your column 1 and column 2. We will add very easy input end output functions.

```
// One point. Has a X and a Y coordinate. Can be easily read and written
struct Point {
    // Data
    double x{};
    double y{};

    // Ultra simple input and output function
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Point& p) { return is >> p.x >> p.y; }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Point& p) { return os << std::setprecision(10) << p.x << " \t " << p.y; }
};
```

Next. This is a curve. It simply consists of many points. We will use a `std::vector` to store the Point elements, because the `std::vector` can grow dynamically. We will add also here very simple input and output functions. For the input, we read Points in a loop and add them to our internal `std::vector`. The output will simply write all values of our `std::vector` to the output stream “os”.

Next, reading the data from a file. Because we already defined the input and outpit operators for a Point and a Curve base on a stream, we can simply use the standard extractor `<<` and inserter `>>` operators.

The first approach will then look like that:

```
int main() {
    // Open the sourcefile with the curve data
    std::ifstream sourceFileStream{"r:\\file.txt"};

    // Check, if we could open the file
    if (sourceFileStream) {

        // Here, we will store our curve data
        Curve curve{};

        // Now read all all points and store them as a curve
        sourceFileStream >> curve;

        // Show debug output
        std::cout << curve;
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
}
```

Hm, looks really cool and simple. But, how does it work? First, we open the file with the constructor of the `std::ifstream`. That is easy. And the nice thing is, the destructor of the `std::ifstream` will close the file for us automatically. This happens on the next closing brace `}`.

Tio check, if the stream is still OK or has a failure, we can simply write `if (sourceFileStream)`. This is possible, because the ``std::ifstream`’s` bool`operator is overwritten. And since the` if` statement expects a Boolean value, this operator is called and informs us, if there is a problem or not. True means no problem. Nice.

Now, lets come to the local peak value search. The problem is often a discrete signal with overlayed noise. Let us look at the following example with a base sinusoid curve and some heavy noise:

[image]

We will add 2 thresholds. An upper and a lower one, or just an upper one but with a negative hysteresis. Sounds complicated, but is not. First, we will check the absolute maximum and absolute minimum value of the curve. Based on that we will calculate the thresholds as percentage values.

We will evaluate value by value and if we pass the upper threshold, we will start looking for a maximum. We will do this until we cross the lower threshold. At this moment, we will store the so far calculated max value (together with its x value). Then, we wait until we cross again the upper threshold. The hysteresis will prevent continuous toggling of the search mode in case of noise.

All this put in code could look like that:

```
std::vector<Point> Curve::findPeaks() {

    // Definition of Threshold value and hysteresis to find max peak values
    constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageHigh{ 0.7 };
    constexpr double Hyteresis{ 0.2 };
    constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageLow{ ThreshholdPercentageHigh - Hyteresis };

    // First find the overall min / max to calculate some threshold data
    const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(points.cbegin(), points.cend(), [](const Point& p1, const Point& p2) { return p1.y < p2.y; });
    const double thresholdMaxHigh = ((max->y - min->y) * ThreshholdPercentageHigh + min->y);
    const double thresholdMaxLow = ((max->y - min->y) * ThreshholdPercentageLow + min->y);


    // We need to know, if the search is active
    // And we need to know, when there is a transition from active to inactive
    bool searchActive{};
    bool oldSearchActive{};

    // Initiliaze with lowest possible value, so that any other value will be bigger
    double maxPeakY{ std::numeric_limits<double>::min() };
    // X value for the max peak value
    double maxPeakX{ std::numeric_limits<double>::min() };

    std::vector<Point> peaks{};

    // Go through all values
    for (size_t index{}; index < points.size(); ++index) {

        // Check,if values are above threshold, then switch on search mode
        if (not searchActive) {
            if (points[index].y > thresholdMaxHigh)
                searchActive = true;
        }
        else {
            // Else, if value is lower than lower threshold, then switch of search mode formaxpeak
            if (points[index].y < thresholdMaxLow)
                searchActive = false;
        }
        // If the search is active, then find the max peak
        if (searchActive)
            if (points[index].y > maxPeakY) {
                maxPeakX = points[index].x;
                maxPeakY = points[index].y;
            }
        // Check for a transition from active to inactive. In that very moment, store the previosuly found values
        if (not searchActive and oldSearchActive) {
            peaks.push_back({ maxPeakX, maxPeakY });
            maxPeakY = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
        }
        // Remember for next round
        oldSearchActive = searchActive;
        searchActive = points[index].y > thresholdMaxHigh;
    }
    return peaks;
}
```

Leading to a final solution with everything put together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

// One point. Has a X and a Y coordinate. Can be easily read and written
struct Point {
    // Data
    double x{};
    double y{};

    // Ultra simple input and output function
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Point& p) { return is >> p.x >> p.y; }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Point& p) { return os << std::setprecision(10) << p.x << " \t " << p.y; }
};

// A curve consists of many pointes
struct Curve {
    // Data
    std::vector<Point> points{};

    // find peaks
    std::vector<Point> findPeaks();

    // Ultra simple input and output function
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Curve& c) { Point p{};  c.points.clear();  while (is >> p) c.points.push_back(p);  return is; }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Curve& c) { for (const Point& p : c.points) os << p << '\n'; return os; }
};

std::vector<Point> Curve::findPeaks() {

    // Definition of Threshold value and hysteresis to find max peak values
    constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageHigh{ 0.7 };
    constexpr double Hyteresis{ 0.2 };
    constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageLow{ ThreshholdPercentageHigh - Hyteresis };

    // First find the overall min / max to calculate some threshold data
    const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(points.cbegin(), points.cend(), [](const Point& p1, const Point& p2) { return p1.y < p2.y; });
    const double thresholdMaxHigh = ((max->y - min->y) * ThreshholdPercentageHigh + min->y);
    const double thresholdMaxLow = ((max->y - min->y) * ThreshholdPercentageLow + min->y);


    // We need to know, if the search is active
    // And we need to know, when there is a transition from active to inactive
    bool searchActive{};
    bool oldSearchActive{};

    // Initiliaze with lowest possible value, so that any other value will be bigger
    double maxPeakY{ std::numeric_limits<double>::min() };
    // X value for the max peak value
    double maxPeakX{ std::numeric_limits<double>::min() };

    std::vector<Point> peaks{};

    // Go through all values
    for (size_t index{}; index < points.size(); ++index) {

        // Check,if values are above threshold, then switch on search mode
        if (not searchActive) {
            if (points[index].y > thresholdMaxHigh)
                searchActive = true;
        }
        else {
            // Else, if value is lower than lower threshold, then switch of search mode formaxpeak
            if (points[index].y < thresholdMaxLow)
                searchActive = false;
        }
        // If the search is active, then find the max peak
        if (searchActive)
            if (points[index].y > maxPeakY) {
                maxPeakX = points[index].x;
                maxPeakY = points[index].y;
            }
        // Check for a transition from active to inactive. In that very moment, store the previosuly found values
        if (not searchActive and oldSearchActive) {
            peaks.push_back({ maxPeakX, maxPeakY });
            maxPeakY = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
        }
        // Remember for next round
        oldSearchActive = searchActive;
        searchActive = points[index].y > thresholdMaxHigh;
    }
    return peaks;
}


int main() {
    // Open the sourcefile with the curve data
    std::ifstream sourceFileStream{"file.txt"};

    // Check, if we could open the file
    if (sourceFileStream) {

        // Here, we will store our curve data
        Curve curve{};

        // Now read all all points and store them as a curve
        sourceFileStream >> curve;

        // Show peaks output
        for (const Point& p : curve.findPeaks()) std::cout << p << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
}
```